# FindViewById returns wrong view

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I use a `ViewFlipper` to alternate between two identical views with an animation.

The xml of this ViewFlipper is as follows.

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/advise_viewflipper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include android:id="@+id/product_select_one" layout="@layout/product_select_view" />
    <include android:id="@+id/product_select_two" layout="@layout/product_select_view" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

Now in my fragment I retrieve both of them with ButterKnife, and fetching their IDs show that they are indeed two different views.

```
currentViewId = currentView.getId();
otherViewId = otherView.getId();
Log.d("Compare", currentView.getId() + " " + otherView.getId());
```

So now inside these two identical view is a `FlowLayout` with id `advise_item_layout`. However, querying this view from **both** views return the same `FlowLayout`.

If I do:

```
final FlowLayout itemLayout = ButterKnife.findById(currentView, R.id.advise_item_layout);
final FlowLayout otherLayout = ButterKnife.findById(otherView, R.id.advise_item_layout);

Log.d("item vs other layout", itemLayout.getId() + " " + otherLayout.getId());
```

The same ids are printed, even though I pass a different view?
The same holds when using FindViewById of Android.

I am aware that FindViewById does a depth first search and grabs the first match, but I am clearly specifying a different view to search in? So what am I doing wrong and what would be the fix?

Comment: You're comparing view ids and they are the same. The views themselves can be different. Check the reference itself e.g. `itemLayout == otherLayout`

Comment: No the parents of the FlowLayout's have different IDs. So I assume they are different objects in memory.

Comment: Anyway the identifiers as returned by `getId()` do not need to be unique and in your case they aren't. You cannot use id for reference identity.

Comment: I know they are not unique, but as I pass the specific parent to it, why do I get in both cases the same FlowLayout returned? So even though I am targeting two different parents, I end up with two references pointing to one parent's  child.

Comment: They are not necessarily the same objects and they just have the same id. Specifically, you're calling `findById()` with `R.id.advise_item_layout` so of course the returned view if any has that specific id.

Comment: `Log.d("Compare", currentView.getId() + " " + otherView.getId());` returns different ids. So I am pretty sure they are different objects. However, `Log.d("item vs other layout", itemLayout.getId() + " " + otherLayout.getId());` reports the SAME id, even though I pass different parents to the `findById` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistaking view identifier as returned by `getId()` with view reference identity. View identifiers do not need to be unique and your view hierarchy has more than one view with the same identifier. The views are still different objects.

> `Log.d("Compare", currentView.getId() + " " + otherView.getId());` return different ids. So I am pretty sure they are different objects

Yes they have different identifiers and also by implication, are different objects.

> However, `Log.d("item vs other layout", itemLayout.getId() + " " + otherLayout.getId());` reports the SAME id, even though I pass different parents to the `findById` function

Yes. Two views can have the same identifier. You are able to find them with the depth-first first-match search since you're starting off the search with a different parent.

If you compared the object references

```
Log.d("item vs other layout", "" + itemLayout == otherLayout);
```

you'd see `false` being logged to actually verify they are different view object.

Comment: Oh right, I get it. Then is there any way to force the two views to have different ids? This is needed for e.g. a fragment transaction that requires an unique ID.